# Minimum and Maximum date for specific group

Tags: mysql, cursor, mysql-workbench

I am examining MySQL workbench database in MAC OS. In this database, there are 2 columns "created_at" and "updated_at", which are present in the majority of the tables, but not all.

I have two tasks at hand. 
First, I want to find the minimum and maximum value of these 2 columns across all tables in the database which have these 2 columns. That will give me a fair idea that the data in the database is from which period to which period.
Second, the "created_at" and "updated_at" is linked to a specific user_id, who also belongs to a specific team. I wish to find the minimum and maximum value of the 2 columns for each team.

How can I write such a query?

Shared a similar question and related answer. I tried the answer offered by other users but it just did not work out in my case. Have no idea how to address the problem. thanks!

[Find minimum and maximum column value of a common column across all tables in a SQL Server 2008 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308899/find-minimum-and-maximum-column-value-of-a-common-column-across-all-tables-in-a)

Comment: Is it a SQL Server or MySQL database?

Comment: It's a MySQL database, am using the workbench to operate on it. My system is Mac OX. thanks!

Comment: Show a typical schema for one or two of the tables, and how they are related to the users table (and it's schema). Edit your question to include this info.

Comment: In other words, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query